# directions between multiple points google map

Tags: javascript, maps

Hello everybody I wanted to link multiple points between them with google map but the problem that it worked with 2 points but not 3 . the coordinates of the points are in the database, I import them with another file using JSON, in my case for example I have 3 points :
 point (A) = paris .. point (B) = berlin.. point (C) = prague 
I wanted: A ----> B ----> C  but the code shows that B ---> C

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     var myObj2= JSON.parse(this.responseText);
     var mapOptions = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.5584308, -70.8597732),zoom: 3,
      };
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
     var directionsDisplay=[];
     for(var i=0;i<myObj2.length-1;i++){//myObj2.length=3
     var depart = new google.maps.LatLng(myObj2[i].latitude, myObj2[i].longitude);// for :i=0 = point(A) .... i=1 =point(B)
    var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(myObj2[i+1].latitude, myObj2[i+1].longitude);//i=1 : point(B)...i=2 =point(C)
     directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
     directionsDisplay[i] = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
      directionsDisplay[i].setMap(map);
      var request = {
        origin: depart,
        destination: destination,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
       };
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
       alert(i) ; // I see that it does not display i = 0 nor i = 1 .... it shows me only i = 2 whereas normally the for-stop loop on i <2 (i = 1)
          directionsDisplay[i].setDirections(response);
        }
      });
    }
    }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "db4.php?datee="+dd1+"&voiture="+dd6, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

I use a for loop and if I test with alert (i), I see that it does not display i = 0 nor i = 1 .... it shows me only i = 2
whereas normally the for-stop loop on i <2 (i = 1)

Comment: can someone please help me :/ ?